# IE8 Standards Mode Kicking into Compatibility Mode Error Log?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

So I'm developing a site and trying to troubleshoot several different browsers and I noticed when I run through my site in IE8 Standards mode sometimes it kicks me out and forces me to goto into IE8 Compatibility mode.

I was wondering if there was any kind of log that this created so I can track down why it did this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't any information exposed by the developer tools that explains why a particular browser and document mode was selected. The tools do show the current selected modes so you could watch for a change but then you have to work out what triggered the change by hand. http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes has some info on how IE8 arrives chooses the modes.